# Xamarin Forms Bluetooth LE not showing nearby discoverable devices

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, bluetooth

I am making an app that utilizes bluetooth function such as scanning devices etc. I checked the scan flag and returns true but not showing the discoverable device that I am testing.

I am using Samsung J7 Pro as my app test device and Samsung J7 as the device I want to see in the list of discovered devices.

J7 already set as discoverable and with bluetooth ON.

I based my codes in [Monkey.BluetoothLE](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.BluetoothLE/)

Here is what I have:

**Declarations**

```
ObservableCollection<BluetoothViewModel> vm = new ObservableCollection<BluetoothViewModel>();
Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothManager _blManager;
Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothManager _blManager;
Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.Adapter _bleAdapter;
```

**Functions**

```
public BluetoothPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lvInfo.ItemsSource = vm;

    var appContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
    _blManager = (Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothManager)appContext.GetSystemService("bluetooth"); 
    _blAdapter = _blManager.Adapter;
    _bleAdapter = new Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.Adapter();

    _bleAdapter.DeviceDiscovered += _bleAdapter_DeviceDiscovered;
    _bleAdapter.ScanTimeoutElapsed += _bleAdapter_ScanTimeoutElapsed;
}

private void btnScanStopBluetooth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_bleAdapter.IsScanning)
    {
        if (!_blAdapter.IsEnabled)
        {
            _blAdapter.Enable();
            DisplayInformation("Turning on bluetooth...");
            while (!_blAdapter.IsEnabled)
            {
                //do nothing until enabled
            }
        }
        vm.Clear();
        btnScan.Text = "Stop Scan";
        _bleAdapter.StartScanningForDevices();
    }
    else
    {
        btnScan.Text = "Start Scan";
        _bleAdapter.StopScanningForDevices();
    }
}

private void _bleAdapter_DeviceDiscovered(object sender, Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.DeviceDiscoveredEventArgs e)
{
    count++;
    vm.Add(new BluetoothViewModel
    {
        Name = e.Device.Name,
        ID = e.Device.ID.ToString(),
        RSSI = e.Device.Rssi.ToString()
    });
}

private void _bleAdapter_ScanTimeoutElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayInformation("Scan Timeout");
    _bleAdapter.StopScanningForDevices();
    btnScan.Text = "Start Scan";
}

private void DisplayInformation(string line)
{
    lblStatus.Text = line;
}
```

A listview is bound to "vm" that will display the discovered device.
It does not show anything, and count is always zero but I checked the scan flag using `_bleAdapter.IsScanning`, it returns true.

EDIT: 
I tried other open-source sample programs for Bluetooth such as

[xamarin-bluetooth-le](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le) (BLE Explorer)

[Bluetooth-Xamarin.Forms](https://julianocustodio.com/2017/12/07/bluetooth/) (DemoBluetooth)

None of them seem to list the device. When I use my built-in bluetooth app under settings, it lists the device. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you granted permission for bluetooth and location?

You have to grant permission in the Manifest/or Settings and depending on the sdk (23+) also asking the user for extra permission.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows